# Get Request Fulfilled Response from Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is the code example of uploading an object using Amazon S3 .

```
public class UploadObjectSingleOperation {
    private static String bucketName     = "*** Provide bucket name ***";
    private static String keyName        = "*** Provide key ***";
    private static String uploadFileName = "*** Provide file name ***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        try {
            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
            File file = new File(uploadFileName);
            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                                     bucketName, keyName, file));

         } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                    "means your request made it " +
                    "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                    " for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                    "means the client encountered " +
                    "an internal error while trying to " +
                    "communicate with S3, " +
                    "such as not being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In this , we can get HTTP status code if we get AmazonServiceException. Is there any way to get HTTP status code for successful response as well ? My aim is to get acknowledged that image is uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out that there is no way to get the HTTPStatus Code for successful response. Just Listening to exceptions is enough to be sure of the succeeded upload .